# Why are valid bearer tokens rejected after half an hour/an hour?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using ASP.NET Web API 2.3 (5.2.3 in NuGet) for RESTful API. Authentication method is bearer token (default by the template). Everything is default generated by the template.

I'm using MySQL database and custom implementation of ASP.NET Identity for MySQL (without EF). Account controller is blocked after creating some default accounts.

When a token is generated, it has the default 14 days valid limit. I uploaded it to Windows Server 2016 Data center version. For some reason, It is denying API access (401 with request denied) with valid token when more than half an hour or more passes.

What is the reason for this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same Issue. 
Create new machine key from IIS and add the machine key under system.web tag in your web.config file.